# How to train a sklearn classifier with a dataset that has varying feature dimension?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, supervised-learning

I hava a dataset of this type.

```
Ingredient_A | Ingredient_B | Ingredient_C | Ingredient_D | Meal
------------------------------------------------------------------
   Bread     |   Butter     |       -      |       -      | buttered bread
   Avocado   |   Tomato     |     Garlic   |       -      | Guacamloe
```

I want to train a sklearn Decision Tree Classifier with it but I don't know how to deal with the varying feature dimensionality of my dataset. Ideally I would want the empty cells to be ignored. I thought about replacing the empty cells with nan's but sklearn doesn't accept nan's. Is there a way of using a dataset like this with sklearn?

Comment: I believe you can use sparse matrices for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your data as vectors like such:

```
(Avocado, Bread, Butter, Garlic, Tomato)
(0,1,1,0,0) = 'Buttered Bread'
(1,0,0,1,1) = 'Guacamloe'
```

Each element in the vector represents the presence of a particular ingredient. You can feed data of this format straight into any classifier, and you won't have issues with implicit ordering.